# Can RingCentral send notifications of new user creates? And then possibly Extension changes?

Tags: provisioning, ringcentral

I am working on a provisioning solution for RingCentral. I understand how to create users in RingCentral.

What I would like is when someone creates a user or changes extension settings in RingCentral to get a notification sent to my app so I can link them.  This way I would have a bidirectional flow of user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe for the Extension List Event described here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Extension-List-Event

The general event filter is as follows:

`/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension`

If you are subscribing for yourself, i.e. the authorizer of the access token being used, you can use the following short notation:

`/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension`

Use this event filter with the Create Subscription API:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Subscriptions/createSubscription

You can also subscribe for a specific extension (user) id.

Here's an excerpt of what this covers:

> Event filter `/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension` enables notifications in case of extension list changes:
>
> - addition/removal of extensions to/from account
> - contact info (first/last name; company name; email; business phone; business address)
>   status
> - regional settings (timezone, home country, language, greeting language, formatting locale, time format)
> - permissions (administrator permission, international calling)
> - phone numbers (assign/unassign)
> - departments (added to/removed from)
> - service features (for the current extension only) - SMS/SMSReceiving, Pager/PagerReceiving, Fax/FaxReceiving, Voicemail, EncryptionAtRest, BlockedMessageForwarding, DnD, RingOut, InternationalCalling, Presence, Conferencing, VoIPCalling, CallPark, OnDemandCallRecording
>   The updated extension data is accessible by calling the methods Get Extension List and/or Get Extension Info